# How get Date and Time from Timestamp to different TextView

Tags: android, timestamp

I have timestamp in DataBase like this: 1472373943.

In my Adapter I would like set Date & Time to different `TextView`.

For Example:[image]

How to separate the date and time? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, what is your input? In your question, it looks like `1472373943`, So I don't know which is time, and date position in that string. For simple, let assume that you have a sample date and time as follows:

```
String date = "12/8/2012";
String time = "11:25 am";
```

So, to convert it. The simple way is

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "12/8/2012";
        String time = "11:25 am";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
        try {
            Date dt = df.parse(date + " " + time);
            Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
            ca.setTime(dt);
            System.out.println(ca.getTimeInMillis());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using two different SimpleDateFormatters on the same Date object, one for the date and the other for the hours. "YYYY/MM/DD" and the other is "HH:mm a", just for an example.

Comment: You just can do it in one SimpleDateFormatlike this
`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");`